# Why to put async await inside an array map callback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

My question related to example i saw (attached below).
The example loads images and then show them on the screen.
As far as i understand the author target was that all the images will be loaded at the same time, but i can't understand how the async await mechanism helps him to achieve this goal?
The problematic lne is:

> imgArr.map(async img => await createImage(img));

Code:

```
  const wait = function (seconds) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
};

 const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.images');

const createImage = function (imgPath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imgPath;

    img.addEventListener('load', function () {
      imgContainer.append(img);
      resolve(img);
    });

    img.addEventListener('error', function () {
      reject(new Error('Image not found'));
    });
  });
};


const loadAll = async function (imgArr) {
  try {
    const imgs = imgArr.map(async img => await createImage(img));
    const imgsEl = await Promise.all(imgs);
    console.log(imgsEl);
    imgsEl.forEach(img => img.classList.add('parallel'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
loadAll(['img/img-1.jpg', 'img/img-2.jpg', 'img/img-3.jpg'])
```

;

Doesn't  **imgArr.map(async img => await createImage(img));** is exactly the same as:

```
for (img of imgArr)
{
    await createImage(img);
}
```

Comment: The `async`/`await` here is pointless. `createImage` already returns a promise, so it's fine to `await Promise.all(imgArr.map(createImage))` on that array of promises. Yes, the images will be requested in parallel, although "all at the same time" is somewhat misleading because some requests are likely to take longer than others.

Comment: `async` function here is pointless. The callback already returns a promise and it doesn't need to wait to make another step there. If there would be a sequence of `async` steps like `createImage` and then `fetchSomething`, using `await` before `createImage` would be justified.

Comment: But how does the images are download at the same time? He showed a graph and the 3 images really was download exactly at the same time

Comment: There’s a browser limit of simultaneous http connections which is a limiting factor.

Comment: @Eitanos30 `await` only blocks code execution in a given `async` function. Since `await createImage(img)` is the only instruction in that function, it blocks nothing. Hence, the images are loaded in parallel.

Comment: @Eitanos30 this code would cause images to load one by one: `const imgsEl = []; for (const img of imgArr) { imgsEl.push(await createImage(img)); }`

Comment: @marzelin,Is there away they will be all download together or at least been displayed exactly at the same time?

Comment: @Eitanos30 if you want them to display at the exact same time, then move the `imgContainer.append(img);` code out of the individual promises and put it after the `Promise.all()` resolves.

Comment: @NicholasTower, thanks a lot. May i ask you if `await someFunction()` can be written only if `someFunction` is declared as **async**?

Comment: @Eitanos30 no, it can be any function that can return anything (for example even `await 1` is a completely valid code though quite useless). But it would make sense if that function return a promise. `async` functions always return a promise.

Comment: @marzelin,thanks... Doesn't the line `  const imgs = imgArr.map(async img => await createImage(img));` **will prevent** from second iteration of the for to start before the **promise** that returned it the first iteration will be settled?

Comment: @Eitanos30 blocking works only for the code in the closest `async` function. The iteration takes place outside of that function so for this reason it can't be blocked. You can't block `map` iteration - it's a synchronous function. You can block inside `async` map callback, but just the code inside of that callback.

Comment: Why you say:`blocking works only for the code in the closest async function`. If a function calls another function so the calling function can be written: `let x = await someSayncFunction();` and the `someSayncFunction` istelf as `await` inside it. Doesn't it the same situation like calling await inside an array callback? I have edited the end of my question

Comment: @Eitanos30 if you have code `[1,2].map(async (n) => { await fetch(n); fetch(n*10) })` Then the `fetch(1)`, `fetch(2)` will be called immediately one after another. But `fetch(10)` only when `fetch(1)` is done and `fetch(20)` when `fetch(2)` is done. In other words `map` creates concurrent execution of `async` callbacks for each of the mapped elements. `let x = await someSayncFunction()` stops the execution of the main function till `someSayncFunction` returns. It's one stream of instructions and there's no concurrency. It's like calling synchronous function by another synchronous function.

Comment: @marzelin. 10x..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code synchronously creates multiple `<img>` elements and sets their `src`s. Setting src on an img causes the browser to start downloading that image, and the browser can download multiple images at once.

The only role that `await` plays in this is that we need to know when the downloading is done. Each image download is wrapped in a promise, then those promises are combined using `Promise.all`. By awaiting the combined promise, we can resume our code once all the downloads are done.

As mentioned in the comments, the `await` in the `.map` is useless.

Comment: but you can see that the line that really display the images is : `imgContainer.append(img);` .  This happen also before the promise gets resolved

Comment: You're correct. If i were writing it, i would move that line out of the promise and do it after the promise resolves.